# There is Possible to use both Mongoose and Mongojs in Meanstack

Tags: mongoose, mean-stack, mongojs

I have a question, I am working in project that uses the MEAN stack Technology and I am using mongojs driver. I need to change to mongoose but I already have a lot of code using mongojs. It's a little bit difficult to refactor the whole code.

My question is if it's possible to use both Mongoose and Mongojs in the same project?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but your code it will be a spaghetti and VERY hard do maintain...

Also you can have performance issues due the conflicts between the mongo connections.

What is your motivation to change the driver? I would suggest to refactor the whole application because it seems to me that you are not using good practises by slitting the dependencies.